# Pass JSX within object to react child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass content to a component that includes link tags, but am getting `[object Object]` instead of the link I am expecting. Is there a way to do this?

parent component

```
const data = {
    title: city,
    content: `click the link ${<a href="/example">here</a>} to continue`
}
return (
    <RandomComponent data={data}
)}
```

child component

```
return (
    <div>
        <p>{data.content}</P>
    </div>
```

currently it is returning

```
click the link [object Object] to continue
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the `content` a JSX element instead.

```
const data = {
    title: city,
    content: <>click the link <a href="/example">here</a> to continue</>
}
```

and then

```
<p>{data.content}</p>
```

will insert it as desired.